# RethinkDB query is not getting any faster by searching by the primary key. Is there any gotcha?

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

I got my `contacts` table populated with 50k records so I could benchmark performance.

What caught my attention was that these queries take aproximatelly the same time to complete:

**Query 1:**

```
r.db('rethinkdb_faker').table('contacts').filter({"id":3453}).limit(1)
```

**Query 2:**

```
r.db('rethinkdb_faker').table('contacts').filter({"name":"contact3453"}).limit(1)
```

They take aproximatelly `160ms` to complete on an I5 1.7ghz Ubuntu server.

I was definitely expecting *Query 1* to run faster because I've read that primary indexes are automatically taken into account. I've also read that *id* is automatically taken as the primary key. Moreover, I didn't find any option to configure the primary key.

Am I doing anything wrong or is this expected?

**EDIT**

Thanks to @mlucy answer, I can now the the result in `13ms` given the same configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the primary index with `get` or `getAll`.  So if you rewrite your first query to be `r.db('rethinkdb_faker').table('contacts').get(3453)` it should be much faster.

Comment: Thanks That worked. Is it true, then, that primaries keys will only be taken into account if I use `get`?

Comment: There are other indexed operations (like `between`), but yeah, the primary index won't be used by `filter`.

Comment: You rock. Thanks again for your attention.